# esc_attr() corrupts json values

Tags: json

Is this a `esc_attr()` and `esc_js()` bug or I am doing something wrong?

```
function _action_escape_test() {
    $json = json_encode(array('test' => '<>\'"[]&quot;'));

    foreach (
        array(
            'esc_attr' => esc_attr($json),
            'esc_js' => esc_js($json),
            'htmlspecialchars' => htmlspecialchars($json, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
        )
        as $func => $esc_value
    ) {
        ?><fieldset class="esc-test">
            <legend><?php echo $func ?>()</legend>
            <textarea data-test-json="<?php echo $esc_value ?>" style="width: 100%"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($esc_value, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?></textarea>
        </fieldset><?php
    }

    ?><script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $('.esc-test').each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);

                try {
                    var json = JSON.parse($this.find('textarea').attr('data-test-json'));

                    $this.css('border', '1px solid green');
                } catch (e) {
                    $this.css('border', '1px solid red');
                }
            });
        });
    </script><?php
}
add_action('admin_notices', '_action_escape_test');
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, when one want to put strings to be used in javascript, `esc_js` is the right function, not `esc_attr`.

The problem is that `esc_js`, according to [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_js):

> Escapes text strings for **echoing** in JS

(bold mine).

So, using with `esc_js` you obtain a string that can be safely echoed in js, not parsed: it's not a bug, it's the intended behaviour.

The *canonical* way to pass data from PHP to js in WordPress is [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) so you should consider to use it instead. (Note that function internally do not use any `esc_*` functions, just echo the result of `json_encode`).

As alternative I can suggest you to use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with [sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php): IMHO it is a far better way to do the task `esc_*` WP functions do.
Consider that `esc_*` function pass through filter hooks, so integrity of your data can be corrupted by *external* code.

Try:

```
<?php
$data_safe = filter_var( $json, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS );
$out_safe = filter_var( $json, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS );
?>
<textarea data-test-json="<?php echo $data_safe; ?>"><?php echo $out_safe; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: In that case, we are thinking to migrate from `esc_attr()` to `htmlspecialchars()`.

We often store in hidden inputs json values: some javascript widget store its value json encoded in a hidden input, on form submit that value is saved in the database, and after page refresh the javascript widget recovers its state from that hidden input json value.

We also use `wp_localize_script()`, but for other cases.

Why they created the `esc_attr()` function if `htmlspecialchars()` is doing its job very well *(I use it in all my non WP projects)* ?

Comment: `esc_attr` do an additional check for valid utf8, call htmlspecialchars then allow filtering results via hooks. That said in my WP projects I use `filter_var` instead: using right filter it can be equivalent to `htmlspecialchars` but is more readable and more flexible: you can wrap it in a custom function where you pass as param the filter constant and/or flags to it. You can use one single method to sanitize all types of variable and you can even create app-specific filters. @moldcraft

Comment: It becomes too complicated for this simple task. I see that filters useless, all you need is to put a value in a attribute. We will just use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `esc_attr()`. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @moldcraft NP. Everyone should be confortable with own code, so if you find `htmlspecialchar` better, go with it, works. What I'm not agree with you: `filter_var` and `filter_var_input` are among the most useful functions in whole PHP: any other way so sanitize / validate generic vars in PHP (expecially user input) just sucks. Example: `htmlspecialchars( $_GET['thing'] )` compared to `filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'thing', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS )` is far far way worse. Worth a read http://www.phparch.com/2010/07/never-use-_get-again/

Comment: We save in the database the original user input, and only make it safe for html when displaying. For validation and removing unwanted characters from a string or input, the `filter_*` functions are good, thank you for the tip. Docs http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php says that `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` is `Equivalent to calling htmlspecialchars() with ENT_QUOTES set.`, so why it is far far way worse?

Comment: Do you notice the direct access to `$_GET`? That's a bad practise in PHP 5. Also it need a check for `isset()`: 2 lines more and an `if` more. That's why. @moldcraft

Comment: Thank you. Someday we will remove all direct access usages from our code.

Comment: This still causes corruption when encoding fails somehow: `data-something="<?php echo filter_var(json_encode(...), FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); ?>"` **edit** I had some encoding issue also, but it works if you one does not have encoding problems.